# Converting the sum : $\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac1n\cot^{-1}(n)$ to an integral.

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration, sequences-and-series

The problem is pretty complicated in my opinion. I wanted to calculate the sum by converting it to integral. Thank you for help.

$$\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac1n\cot^{-1}(n)$$

Comment: are you sure that your sum does converge?

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner It does, by WolframAlpha: http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sum_(n%3D1)%5Einfinity+(cot%5E(-1)(n))%2Fn

Comment: Perhaps the question "I wanted to calculate the sum by converting it to integral." is a little vague.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that
$$\int_0^{\infty } \frac{\exp (-n x) \sin (x)}{x} \, dx=\cot ^{-1}(n)$$
And so,
$$\color{red}{\sum _{n=1}^{\infty } \frac{\cot ^{-1}(n)}{n}}=\sum _{n=1}^{\infty } \frac{\int_0^{\infty } \frac{\exp (-n x) \sin
   (x)}{x} \, dx}{n}=\int_0^{\infty } \frac{\sin (x) \sum _{n=1}^{\infty } \frac{\exp (-n x)}{n}}{x} \,
   dx=\int_0^{\infty } \frac{\sin (x) \left(-\log \left(1-e^{-x}\right)\right)}{x} \, dx=\color{red}{\int_0^{\infty } -\frac{\sin
   (x) \log \left(1-e^{-x}\right)}{x} \, dx}$$

Comment: I'm curious to know why this answer was accepted.

Answer (score 8):

Note that

$$\cot^{-1}(x)=\int_x^\infty\frac{{\rm d}t}{1+t^2}$$

By letting $t\mapsto x/u$,

$$\cot^{-1}(x)=\int_0^1\frac{x{\rm~d}u}{u^2+x^2}$$

And so,

$$\frac1n\cot^{-1}(n)=\int_0^1\frac{{\rm d}u}{u^2+n^2}$$

Now we may use

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac1{u^2+n^2}=\frac\pi{2u}\coth(\pi u)-\frac1{2u^2}$$

And so,

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac1n\cot^{-1}(n)=\frac12\int_0^1\left(\frac\pi u\coth(\pi u)-\frac1{u^2}\right){\rm~d}u$$

which is hopefully what you wanted.

Comment: (+1) to you too. It would be interesting to show how our integral representations turn out to be equivalent.

Comment: Is it possible to get numerical result?

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio It appears I can reach your series of zeta's by taking the Laurent series of $\coth(\pi u)$ at zero.

Comment: @MariannaKalwat One manner is to [series expand $\coth$](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=series(coth(x),0)), which gives some bounds to the series.

Comment: @MariannaKalwat What? $\cot^{-1}(n)\ne\cot(n)$ for all natural $n>1$, and your sentence doesn't make sense. Where is $x$?

Comment: I mean, is possible to write $coth(πu)$ as the combination of $cos(πu)$ and $sin(πu)?

Comment: @MariannaKalwat No,$$\coth(x)=\frac{e^x+e^{-x}}{e^x-e^{-x}}$$

Answer (score 8):

As an alternative approach,
$$\sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{1}{n}\arctan\frac{1}{n} = \sum_{n\geq 1}\sum_{k\geq 0}\frac{(-1)^k}{(2k+1) n^{2k+2}}=\sum_{k\geq 0}\frac{(-1)^k \zeta(2k+2)}{(2k+1)} $$
can be written as
$$ \sum_{k\geq 0}\frac{(-1)^k}{(2k+1)\cdot(2k+1)!}\int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{x^{2k+1}}{e^x-1}\,dx = \color{red}{\int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{\text{Si}(x)}{e^x-1}\,dx} $$
where $\text{Si}(x)=\int_{0}^{x}\frac{\sin(t)}{t}\,dt$. This is just a consequence of $\mathcal{L}\left(\text{Si } x\right)(s)=\frac{1}{s}\arctan\frac{1}{s}$.

Comment: Lots of +1/-1 votes going around =/

Comment: @SimplyBeautifulArt: well, I believe the answer is correct and does what the OP wants, so I will just keep close my dear downvoter and wish him/her a merry Christmas. An explanation would be a kind gesture, but I am not willing to bet it will arrive.