# Summing an Arctangent Series

Tags: sequences-and-series, fourier-series

I ran across this series involving arctan and I am very curious to know if it has a closed form.

$$
\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{k}\arctan{\frac{1}{k}}
$$

It looks too devilishly simple to not have a wonderful closed form.
For a little context a series like this will arise from integrating the relationship:
$$
\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{k^2+x^2}=\frac{\pi\coth\pi x}{2x}-\frac{1}{2x^2}
$$
Thanks for any help!

Comment: $\arctan 1/x \approx 1/x$ except for small values of $x$ (in fact, $\frac{1}{x} > \arctan(1/x)$ for $x \in \mathbb R$). Comparing this with the Basel series allows you to approximate the value of the series, for example, $\arctan 1 + \frac{1}{2} \arctan \frac{1}{2} + \frac{\pi^2}{6} - \frac{1}{1^2} - \frac{1}{2^2} \approx 1.412$, whereas the true value is around $1.401$ according to [WA](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sum+%5Cfrac%7B1%7D%7Bx%7D%5Carctan%5Cleft%28%5Cfrac%7B1%7D%7Bx%7D%5Cright%29+from+1+to+infinity).

Comment: Related: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2581766/converting-the-sum-sum-limits-n-1-infty-frac1n-cot-1n-to-an-integ

Comment: From the Maclaurin series of $x \arctan x$, substitute $x \mapsto 1/x$ to obtain an approximation centered around $x = \infty$ ($\frac{1}{x^2} - \frac{1}{3x^4} + \frac{1}{5x^6} + \cdots (-1)^n \frac{1}{(2n-1)x^{2n}}$ indexed from $n=0$). Using values for even powers of the zeta function, there might be a way in.

Comment: Lots of "devilishly simple" things don't actually have (elementary) closed forms.

Comment: @J.M.ain'tamathematician ... But lots do. Heck even lots of devilishly complicated things have closed forms too.

Comment: There aren't that many elementary or special functions, but there are infinitely many expressions involving them. It stands to reason that it is more likely than not that some combination of them in a sum or integral will lead to something intractable.

Answer (score 1):

$$S=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{k}\tan ^{-1}\left(\frac{1}{k}\right)$$

Using
$$\frac{1}{k}\tan ^{-1}\left(\frac{1}{k}\right)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{2 n-1}\frac 1 {k^{2n}}$$ Changing the order of summation
$$S=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} (-1)^{n+1} \frac{\zeta (2 n)}{2 n-1}=1.405869298287780\cdots$$ This number is not recognized by inverse symbolic calculators.